# How to assign fetchedObjects to a variable independently

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my case i 'm getting my nsmanagedobjects into an array with line of

```
let rows = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as [Row]
```

after this line i rollback changes as my needs

```
managedObjectContext?.rollback()
```

and i am supposed to use the values of the rows variable. But due to rollback() function changes in rows are also deleted.

How can i keep my data for after rollback() function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"But due to rollback() function changes in rows are also deleted."*

That's because this is specifically what that method is documented to do. The documentation says:

> Removes everything from the undo stack, discards all insertions and deletions, and restores updated objects to their last committed values.

The entire purpose of calling `rollback` is to get rid of any unsaved changes in the context, so what you describe is the expected behavior.

If you want to keep changes *and* call `rollback` for some reason, you would have to copy those changes to someplace not affected by the managed object context, then I guess copy them back later on. That will be a pain in the ass, but it's possible.

The real question is why you are calling `rollback`-- a method specifically designed to undo unsaved changes-- if you have changes you don't want to undo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this answer led me to the solution... I needed to use rollback() this way. I achieved to keep my data assigning my models in a array of dictionaries.